# exporting a blender model to opengles and render it on iphone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, blender

hi am noob at blender and opengles.for the last two days i was trying to create a 3d model using blender finally i could make something from it,and now i need to export the model(created using blender) so as to render it on iphone.what is the best way to acheive this i.e  how to export this file and use it in opengles to render it on the iphone..thanks in adavance....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an tutorial on loading an 3D model in openGL ES on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914632/is-there-an-tutorial-on-loading-an-3d-model-in-opengl-es-on-the-iphone)

Comment: The answer to that question provides a step-by-step guide to do exactly what you want.

Comment: hi Brad,finally i had created a 3d model using blender and able to render it on the device,rightnow i need to rotate the 3d object using ui gestures on the device,could you suggest me the best idea for implementing that.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @ravoorinandan - Perhaps my answer to this question would be of use: [Where can I find an iPhone OpenGL ES Example that responds to touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039481/where-can-i-find-an-iphone-opengl-es-example-that-responds-to-touch)

Comment: @Brad- I had gone through it but i still have  a doubt regarding how they are projecting the object???they had used glfrustumf function and other conversion matrices!!!as a noob am unable to understand all the terms what they had used to make the object rotate through touches!!!!

Comment: @Brad:- i had seen your molecules applicaion!firstly i need to congratulate you for the good work done,but as a noob i found something problamatic in understanding touches.please tel me the possible way to understand and learn that.

Comment: @ravoorinandan - I describe a little bit about the technique I use to alter the model view matrix in my posts [here] (http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/10/22/3-d-rotation-without-trackball) and [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2009/01/13/opengl-es-catransform3d), although I don't really explain the math involved in manipulating the model view matrix the way I do.  If this gives you trouble, I highly recommend reading a book like iPhone 3D Graphics by Philip Rideout to get the background information you need.

Comment: @Brad:-thanks a lot for your replies.i will go through the book you suggested and try to achieve the functionality.once again thanks a lot for guiding me all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those having issues with the latest version of Blender and the export plugin, I've managed to fix the problem and create a new version that is compatible with 2.62+.

I've sent Jeff LaMarche a pull request but in the meantime you can get it from here

https://github.com/rpassis/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff/tree/master/Blender%20Export/objc_blend_2.62

Cheers,

Rog